# PHP-based PDF file download not working in Chrome; can't be downloaded securely

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, download

I have this PHP script to download a PDF file from the website:

```
<?php   
    $filename = $_GET['file'];  
    
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/"; //path of this file
    $fullPath = $path.$filename; //path to download file

    $filetypes = array("rar","zip","pdf");

    if (strpos($fullPath, $baseDir) == false) {
       echo "Invalid download dir.";
       exit;
    }       
    
    if (!in_array(substr($filename, -3), $filetypes)) {
       echo "Invalid download type.";
       exit;
    }

    if (file_exists($fullPath) == false) {
       echo "No, thanks.";
       exit;    
    }

    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {    
        //the next part outputs the file
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);

        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($_GET['file'])."");
        header("Content-length: ".$fsize);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly

        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }           
    }

    fclose ($fd);
    exit;
?>
```

In the .htaccess I have got this:

```
# DOWNLOAD TRACK
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(rar|zip|pdf)$ /download.php?file=$1.$2 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

And it doesn't work when I click on the link on the site (nothing happens), only with Save link as... menu, and with this I receive a message:

> can't be downloaded securely

In Firefox it works. In Edge it works but with the message.

Any idea what should I change to work in Chrome and without the security message?

Comment: Did you try `header("Content-type: application/pdf");`

Comment: The result is the same. :(